# Django query accessing data

Tags: django

How do I access the data from the user from another table? I just want to extract a number from a database for specifically loggedIn user.

Then use it for another function. The number is in another table, but I have used the user as a foreign key.

Here is my `view.py`:

```
def showform(request):
    form = FormNumber()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        phone = customer.objects.filter(phone='phone')
        print(phone)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'mpesa/pay.html', context)
```

Here is my `model.py`:

```
class customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Comment: would you show the **number Model**.

Comment: No actually i dont have a number model, i was just tryng to fetch the phone-number then i dec;aire it as a number

Comment: It brings an error File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\RegistrationLoginForm\RegistrationLogin\mpesa_api\views.py", line 26, in showform
    print(phone.phone)
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'phone'

Comment: when you get the customer as `phone = customer.objects.filter(phone='phone')` it definitely has `phone` attribute to access it as `phone.phone`. did you run `migration` commands ?

Comment: and also don't forget to get the specific object as the `phone = customer.objects.filter(phone='phone')` returns list of customers your could get the first object as `phone.first()` then `phone.first().phone`. or any object like the last one by `phone.last()` or any.. 

you can loop through all of them 
`for customer in phone: 
    print(customer.phone)
`

Comment: Yes, but still bores those errors

Comment: It brings none when i use  phone.last() / phone.first(), customer.phone also brings empty

Comment: so there is no customer matching that phone number. try other phone number while filtering or create a customer with phone number you are trying with.

Comment: @AliAref the main function, i want to fetch the hone-number of the loggedIn user, nt everyone, because i want to use the number to carry out another function

Comment: the logged in phone number would be `phone = customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)` then `if phone.exsist(): print("logged in user phone number ", phone.first()) else: print("logged in user doesn't have phone number")`